# Che cosa vuol dire “sostenibilità” in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Ieri è stato annunciato il nuovo libro della Rowling, *Il Maialino di Natale*, e sul [comunicato stampa rilasciato dalla Salani](https://www.adnkronos.com/jk-rowling-e-il-maialino-di-natale-nuovo-libro-il-12-ottobre_23GXgpwT5Ofqyhu5ltndUc) è riportato:

> La sua affettuosa, inesauribile fantasia e la compassione verso le persone e gli oggetti amati che assorbono i sentimenti umani è la celebrazione del calore della famiglia, del prendersi cura e del sentirsi capiti e della autentica sostenibilità delle cose.

Ma esattamente cosa significa  “autentica sostenibilità delle cose”? È da ieri che mi sforzo per riuscire a capirne il senso.

Comment: Dopo aver letto l'intero articolo linkato, direi che non significa assolutamente nulla; mi sembra semplicemente un'espressione buttata lì perché "di tendenza" ed evocativa di qualcosa che oggi è percepito come positivo. Puro _marketing_, a mio parere.

Comment: Mi sono permesso qualche ritocco estetico alla domanda.

Comment: Grazie a tutti per le risposte :)

Comment: Potreste per favore evitare di dare risposte nei commenti?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Non vedo risposte nei commenti: sia la mia sia, direi, quella di secan sono opinioni personali (“direi che... mi sembra... a mio parere”, “sono d'accordo che sembra...”) e sarebbero inaccettabili come risposte.

Comment: @DaG Chiaramente il richiedente la pensa diversamente, visto che dice "grazie a tutti per le risposte" e si dichiara soddisfatto. E quei due post mi sembra che siano più accettabili come risposte che come commenti, visto che non suggeriscono migliorie alla domanda.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Che c'entra? Il richiedente, che è anche un ‘new contributor’, potrebbe non aver presente come dev'essere fatta una risposta in questo sito.

Answer (score 3):

Dopo aver letto l'intero articolo linkato, direi che non significa assolutamente nulla; mi sembra semplicemente un'espressione buttata lì perché "di tendenza" ed evocativa di qualcosa che oggi è percepito come positivo. Puro marketing, a mio parere. – secan

Comment: Non mi sembra corretto inserire questa come risposta. Pur condividendone ogni parola e stimando @secan, non trovo coerente con i criteri di questo sito considerare risposta un commento formato esplicitamente da opinioni (“direi che... mi sembra... a mio parere”).

Comment: @DaG Allora puoi usare il flag "not an answer" e lasciare la decisione ai moderatori.

Comment: L'avevo già fatto, @FedericoPoloni. Per chi mi hai preso? :)

Comment: @DaG - gli eventuali voti non vanno a mio favore, giusto per chiarire. È solo un modo per mettere in evidenza un commento che può essere una risposta. È non metodo diffuso in altri siti più frequentati.

Comment: Concordo con @DaG; la mia è solo una delle possibili interpretazioni, non una risposta certa. Pur essendo riportata in un virgolettato, quella frase potrebbe essere stata estratta da un discorso più ampio che ne avrebbe in qualche modo chiarito il significato, rendendo giustificato l'uso dell'espressione termine "sostenibilità delle cose". Espressione che, per inciso, a mio avviso non è l'unica discutibile; anche il concetto di "fantasia _affettuosa_" mi lascia molto perplesso.

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, in linea di principio hai fatto bene e capita che ci siano commenti che funzionano in realtà come risposte. È solo che in questo caso non è così, come osserva secan stesso.

Comment: @DaG - i voti ricevuti sembra indicare diversamente. Ad essere scrupolosi la domanda è  “opinion-based” infatti come osservato la risposta “è una delle possibili interpretazioni”. Ma se scegliamo di tenerla aperta altre “interpretazioni” possono essere aggiunte.

Comment: @Hachi - una nota a margine su "_i voti ricevuti sembra indicare diversamente_": la popolarità di un'opinione non ne implica necessariamente la correttezza. Parlo in linea generale, sia chiaro. ;)